# Python Integration with PowerBi

Tags: python, powerbi

I am running a python script by doing following two steps

Open Power BI First

Step 1: Get data > Other > Python script > Ok (for running)

Step 2: Navigator > Selecting the data frames > Load

The python script in Step 1 does the below things.
a) Reading input files (csv and text files from one folder from my system)
b) Performing appending/adding some new columns etc.
c) storing some different results in some data frames

As we see, I want to have a one click solution. Meaning, I do not want to load the files manually (selecting data frames manually and click Load button). Is there any way I can simply run python script in Power Bi (mentioned in Step 1), script executes and load the python script output (data frames) automatically into power BI? I really do not want to run the script once and load the data frames into power BI by clicking them manually.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the user's role is here. Are they running python scripts on their computer or triggering them to be run somehow? Are they working in Power BI Desktop?

Comment: Hi Alexis, sorry for the confusion. There is no user. I personally do not want to run the script once and load the data frames into power BI by clicking them manually. Edited the last line in question.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure it's possible to do exactly what you're after but maybe there's a good alternative. What's the main reason you're looking to reduce clicks? Are you loading a bunch of tables from a single python script? Are you running the script on a bunch of different input files?

Comment: Python Script: Reading few input files which are located on my laptop through python. Then preforming some operations on those inputs and storing the result in few data frames.  I run this single python script in power BI, the output of the script (5 data frames) would appear in Navigator window of power BI. Here, we need to select those data frames and click load button (to load them into power BI). Actually, these data frames are loaded into one power BI template (already created having some charts and tables). Every month, we need to run this template with new data(but same columns)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.